# could not find implicit value for parameter tupler

Tags: scala, tuples, shapeless, hlist

In the code below I am trying to create a HList of Lists but I am facing a compile time error on the last line of this code as:

> ◾could not find implicit value for parameter tupler:
>   shapeless.ops.hlist.Tupler[shapeless.HList] ◾not enough arguments for
>   method tupled: (implicit tupler:
>   shapeless.ops.hlist.Tupler[shapeless.HList])tupler.Out. Unspecified
>   value parameter tupler.

```
object Problem extends App {

  def combinations[T](n: Int, ls: List[T]) = {

    import shapeless._
    import HList._

    def prepareHListR(t: Int, result: HList): HList = t match {
      case t if (t == 0) => result
      case _             => prepareHListR(t - 1, rotateLeft(t - 1, ls) :: result)
    }

    prepareHListR(n, HNil)

  }

  def rotateLeft[A](i: Int, xs: List[A]) = {
    val rot = if (i > 0) i else xs.length + i
    xs.drop(rot) ++ xs.take(rot)
  }

  println(combinations(3, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f)))

}
```

**Output:**

> List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f) :: List('b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f, 'a) :: List('c, 'd, 'e, 'f, 'a, 'b) :: HNil

What next I need to do is to create a tuple of these lists as below:

> (List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f), List('b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f, 'a), List('c, 'd, 'e, 'f, 'a, 'b))

For which I am trying:

```
combinations(3, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f)).tupled
```

---

This approach however is working fine on REPL:

```
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> import HList._
import HList._

scala> val hlist = List(1, 2, 3) :: List(4, 5, 6) :: List(7, 8, 9) :: HNil
hlist: shapeless.::[List[Int],shapeless.::[List[Int],shapeless.::[List[Int],shapeless.HNil]]] = List(1, 2, 3) :: List(4, 5, 6) :: List(7, 8, 9) :: HNil

scala> val t  =hlist.tupled
t: (List[Int], List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1, 2, 3),List(4, 5, 6),List(7, 8, 9))
```

---

To me this seems like an issue with *type parameter* but I am not able to understand it due to mine limited knowledge in both Scala and Shapeless.

Any help is much appreciated! TIA.

Comment: Right, you're probably missing a type parameter (and a piece of implicit evidence). If you could provide a complete example (with imports and all definitions) it would be easier to diagnose.

Comment: @TravisBrown Thanks for your reply. I have updated the post with the working code and further explanations.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of related issues here, but the important point is that the size of the tuple depends on a value that's only known at runtime (which is a problem). The `HList` version works, but only because you're throwing away the types. You're ending up with something that's statically typed as `HList`, which you can do practically nothing with (except pattern match at runtime), and which generally isn't what you want.

You can write a version of this that gives you a nice, statically tuple-typed result, but it's a little more work, and it puts a constraint on your `n` argument. First you need a custom type class:

```
import shapeless._, ops.tuple.{ Last, Prepend }

trait Rotated[N <: Nat, A] extends DepFn1[List[A]]

object Rotated {
  type Aux[N <: Nat, A, Out0] = Rotated[N, A] { type Out = Out0 }

  implicit def rotated0[A]: Aux[nat._1, A, Tuple1[List[A]]] =
    new Rotated[nat._1, A] {
      type Out = Tuple1[List[A]]

      def apply(l: List[A]): Tuple1[List[A]] = Tuple1(l)
    }

  implicit def rotatedN[N <: Nat, A, OutN, LA](implicit
    rotN: Aux[N, A, OutN],
    last: Last.Aux[OutN, LA],
    ev: LA <:< List[A],
    prep: Prepend[OutN, Tuple1[List[A]]]
  ): Aux[Succ[N], A, prep.Out] =
    new Rotated[Succ[N], A] {
      type Out = prep.Out

      def apply(l: List[A]): prep.Out = {
        val resultN = rotN(l)
        val lastList = ev(last(resultN))
        prep(resultN, Tuple1(lastList.drop(1) ++ lastList.take(1)))
      }
    }
}
```

There are several ways you could write that. The version above is off-the-cuff but probably reasonable.

Now your `combinations` method looks like this:

```
def combinations[T, O <: HList](n: Nat, ls: List[T])(implicit
  rotN: Rotated[n.N, T]
): rotN.Out = rotN(ls)
```

And then the usage is exactly what you asked for:

```
scala> combinations(3, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f))
res0: (List[Symbol], List[Symbol], List[Symbol]) = (List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f),List('b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f, 'a),List('c, 'd, 'e, 'f, 'a, 'b))

scala> combinations(2, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f))
res1: (List[Symbol], List[Symbol]) = (List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f),List('b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f, 'a))
```

Now you're getting back tuples, at the cost of not being able to do something like this:

```
scala> val x = 4
x: Int = 4

scala> combinations(x, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f))
<console>:20: error: Expression x does not evaluate to a non-negative Int literal
       combinations(x, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f))
                    ^
```

But if you think about it that's a reasonable constraint—if you want a tuple whose size is available at compile time, you need to specify that size in a way that's available at compile time.